# CSS Animations (flip) won't work on Iphone/Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I got this CSS Animation that flips an image to another image which is awesome after I got help from this forum on how to add a vendor prefix to get it to work in Safari. Unfortunately it still doesn't work on Iphone :(

Anyone know how to solve this?

CODE:

```
<body>
    <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/332">
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/331">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes flip {
from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); transform: rotateY(0deg); }
to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: rotateY(180deg); }
}

@keyframes flip {
from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); transform: rotateY(0deg); }
to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: rotateY(180deg); }
}


/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
perspective: 1000;
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
width: 600px;
height: 332px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
transition: 1s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
position: relative;
-webkit-animation-name: flip;
animation-name: flip;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
animation-delay: 3s;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
backface-visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
-webkit-backface-visibility: 1000px;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
background: white;
z-index: 2;
/* for firefox 31 */
transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should review and apply vendor prefix for ALL required properties (such as perspective, transform-style, transition also).

Also you should add units to perspective property (for example: -webkit-perspective: 1000px).

Practically, to prevent code overloading by vendor prefixes use **-prefix-free** javascript library.

When you using **-Prefix-free** javascript library you don`t care about vendor prefixes.

Official site is here: http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where can I find the -prefix-free javascript library?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');"` in all your div's in html and add below javascript.

```
$('.flip-container').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.flipper').addClass('hover').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
    return false;
});
```